# Solve $xu_x + u_y = 3x - u$ with $u(x,0) = \tan^{-1} x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve $xu_x + u_y = 3x - u$ with $u(x,0) = \tan^{-1} x$.

First, we can check that the curve $\{t = 0\}$ is non-characteristic for the given PDE. Indeed, $(x,1) \cdot (0,1) = 1 \ne 0$. Next, using Charpit's equations,
$$\frac{dx}{x} = dy = \frac{dz}{3x-z}$$
Integrating $\frac{dx}{x} = dy$, we get
$$\log x - y = c_1 \tag{1}$$
How do I get another equation with another arbitrary constant? The $3x-z$ below $dz$ is troubling me, since neither $\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dz}{3x-z}$ nor $dy = \frac{dz}{3x-z}$ can be directly integrated, even after using $(1)$. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ln|x|-y=c_1$ is correct.
$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dz}{3x-z} \quad\implies\quad \frac{dz}{dx}=3-\frac{z}{x}$$
This is a first order linear ODE that one solves for $z(x)$.
$$z(x)=\frac32 x+c_2\frac{1}{x}$$
The solution of the PDE (without condition) is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac32 x+\frac{1}{x}F\big(\ln|x|-y\big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined in order to satisfy the conditon $u(x,0)=\tan^{-1}(x)$

I suppose that you can find the function $F$ and finally :
$$u(x,y)=\frac32 x+e^{-y}\tan^{-1}\big(x e^{-y} \big)$$